# SQL Query to return last week's data

Tags: sql, ssis, ssrs-2008

I am trying to run a sql query that will return last week's data to the date. For example, today is Monday. I want to return last Monday's data only. The prior week to the day. What I am doing is getting last week's ARAging Snapshot for my company. (What the data was last Monday, compared to this Monday)

Here is my query but, I am not sure it's correct.

```
select * from ARAgingReportLine
where ReportRunDate  = DATEADD(week, - 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: it should be >=

Comment: Ok. Thanks, but, this gives me all dates from today and then back 7 days. I only want the data from 7 days ago, which is last Monday which is one day's worth of data.

Comment: you can get the days of teh week and remove it wit dayadds and so you have Monday of this week and from that subtract 1 week so you have last weeks monday

Comment: Ok. How do I do that in my query? I'm not familiar with the dayadds function.

Comment: Also, I need the day of the past week no matter what day it is.

Comment: i am actually quite confused which data you want can you provide data and the wanted result,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that your `ReportRunDate` is a datetime rather than a datew. So, with times included, comparing to just the date will only shows records run at midnight.

Try casting both side of the comparison to `Date` datatypes, this will remove the time portion and give you the matches you want.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ARAgingReportLine
    WHERE CAST(ReportRunDate AS Date) = CAST(DATEADD(week, - 1, GETDATE()), AS Date)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan Scholfield! That did the trick!

Comment: Glad to help. Could you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left below the vote up/down buttons). This helps others with similar questions find answers faster. It also gives you reputation which increases what you can d on StackOverflow. You should also consider reviewing some of your older questions to see if answers should be accepted or not.